# How to hide mouse cursor when window is clicked and being used but how to make it re appear when escape is pressed

Tags: c++, glfw

Ok so I figured out how to hide the cursor when my game first starts and then I am able to make it re-appear when I press escape using `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);` to hide cursor and `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);` to make it re-appear. And using `glfwSetWindowFocusCallback(window, window_focus_callback);` to callback whenever the window goes into focus or not. **But** the problem is if I just press escape and my cursor is returned if I click on the window again nothing happens even though it should technically be in focus again right? Does anybody know how to fix this or implement this in a better way? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I don't know if this might be part of the problem but for my escape function all I do is call my window focus callback function like this `window_focus_callback(window, 0);` setting the window to be not focused with the 0 and I also set the windows attribute to not be focused like this `glfwSetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_FOCUSED, 0);` to make sure the window is out of focus. Also if you are wondering my window focus callback function is :

```
void window_focus_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int focused){
    if(focused){
        mouse_enabled = true;
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    }
    else{
        mouse_enabled = false;
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean check the return value of `glfwSetInputMode` isnt it a void function lol

Comment: Yes, you're right. From the `Errors` section, I concluded that there's a return value.